# Send page title, page URL, link title and link href, with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, this

I'm new to jQuery and I am trying to develop a click counter.
jQuery => Ajax => PHP => MySQL
So I've got this construction:

```
function clck(id) {
    $.post(
        'http://counter:8888/sts/click.php', {
        id: id,
        htmltitle: (document.title + " <br/> " + '(' + document.location.href + ')'),
        clicktitle: ($("$this\[onClick\]").attr("title") + " <br/> " + '(' + $("$this\[onClick\]").attr("href") + ')')
    });
}
```

And I'm using this call for jQuery:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onClick="javascript:clck(1)" title="google1">google 1</a>
<a href="http://fb.com" onClick="javascript:clck(2)" title="fb 2">fb 2</a>
```

So it works great for the first link, but when I press the second link, it writes the same in the first link.
What I need is: page title, page URL, link title and link href.
And all of this must be sent separate by Ajax to PHP.

---

---

Thank's a lot to J_Caselles (it works great), poncha and rtpHarry
So, working code for me:

```
function clck(id) {
 $.post(
     'http://counter:8888/sts/click.php', {
     id: id.split("link_")[1],
     htmltitle: document.title + " <br/> (" + document.location.href + ")",
     clicktitle: $("#" + id).attr("title") + " <br/> (" + $("#" + id).attr("href") + ")"
 });}
```

and call

```
<a id="link_1" href="http://google.com" title="google1" onClick="javascript:clck(this.id)">google 1</a>
<a id="link_2" href="http://fb.com" title="fb 2" onClick="javascript:clck(this.id)">fb 2</a>
```

Comment: you have a typo in `clicktitle` (written as `clicktitile`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the actual id of the link (and of course provide it first).

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="link1" onClick="javascript:clck(this.id)" title="google1">google 1</a>
<a href="http://fb.com" id="link2" onClick="javascript:clck(this.id)" title="fb 2">fb 2</a>
```

Then you select the link with the id. Simple.

```
function clck(id) {
     $.post(
         'http://counter:8888/sts/click.php', {
         id: id.split("link")[1],
         htmltitle: document.title + " <br/> " + '(' + document.location.href + ')'),
         clicktitle: $("#" + id).attr("title") + " <br/> " + '(' + $("#" + id).attr("href") + ')')
     });
}
```

Comment: using onclick and javascript: links is not considered a modern way to develop websites - please look up unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: there's also a slight problem with `id` passed (easy to fix though). the original code passed an integer, while this one passes "link1" (DOM id)

Comment: so, first i need to clean up "id" via str.replace?

Comment: @poncha It's not recommended to have numerical id's.

Comment: @J_Caselles while it is not recommended in **DOM** to have numerical IDs, server-side application logic (and database) almost certainly use numerical ids. But you can reconstruct it from your element ids, too. Thats why i said it can be easily fixed.

Comment: @J_Caselles but i need to send numerical id to MySql. that is a problem. I can clean it in jQuery or in PHP, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndreySolovev added a cleaner solution than str.replace to extract the int from the id. id.split("link")[1]

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
$("a").click(function () {
  $.post(
    'http://counter:8888/sts/click.php', {
    id: $(this).data("linkid"),
    htmltitle: (document.title + " <br/> " + '(' + document.location.href + ')'),
    clicktitle: $(this).attr("title") + " <br/> (" + $this.attr("href") + ")";
  });
});
```

And then do my markup like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" data-linkid="1" title="google1">google 1</a>
<a href="http://fb.com" data-linkid="2" title="fb 2">fb 2</a>
```

Comment: There is one thing, i need to find ("a"), that have got attribute [onClick]. And it works =) but for the first link. =(

And yes, it will be better to wright " <br/> (" Thanks for this.

Comment: Might have added some class at least to trigger only on specific links, not any `<a>` tag in document ;) otherwise, this is good.

Comment: J_Caselles told me the same, but to do with id.

Comment: @AndreySolovev this is not the same. This solution attaches to events externally, without use of `onclick` in the html code...